# Why series expansion doesn’t work

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, fake-proofs, euler-maclaurin

The Euler Maclaurin Formula is $$\sum_{k=0}^x f(k)=\int_0^xf(t)dt+\frac{f(x)+f(0)}2+R_1\tag{1}$$Where $R_1$ is the remainder term defined as (according to Wikipedia)$$R_p=\frac{(-1)^{p+1}}{p!}\int_0^xf^{(p)}(t)P_p(t)dt\tag{2}$$I also know that $$\sum_{k=0}^xf(k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(f(k)-f(k+x))$$Where $f(k)\rightarrow0$. Taking the derivative on both sides of equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ and setting them equal, we get $$-\sum_{k=0}^\infty f’(k+x)=f(x)+f'(x)\left(P_1(x)+\frac12\right)$$Solving for $f(x)$: $$f(x)=-\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty f'(k+x)+f'(x)\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)\right)$$Since $P_1(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor -\frac12$. If this series expansion was true, then it would be very well known as we take only the first derivative of the function $f(x)$. This was already a red flag, so I tried $f(x)=\frac1{x+1}$ and I found that it wasn't true. Is there something wrong with my derivation? I think this might have to do with the remainder term (the solution is very straightforward, so making mistakes is unlikely) being false because it comes from Wikipedia. However, I found a [PDF](https://people.csail.mit.edu/kuat/courses/euler-maclaurin.pdf) from MIT that suggests the same thing written in a different form.

Comment: The usual meaning of $f(n)\sim g(n)$ is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1$, so $f(k)\sim 0$ makes no sense. You probably meant $f(n)\to 0$.

Comment: @jjagmath yes, that's true. I tried to act fancy honestly.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^x f(k)$ is piecewise constant and discontinuos at the integers, so you can't expect taking the derivative to make sense.

Comment: @jjagmath I am taking the derivative of its analytic continuation.

Comment: What do you think is the analytic continuation?

Comment: @jjagmath It is the RHS of $(1)$ and $(2)$. Coming to think about it, they might not actually be equal. They should be the same at integers though.

Comment: Both Wikipedia and the PDF you reference seem to me only to state these results when $x$ is a natural number.

Comment: @ancientmathematician The formula does not work for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I did not mention the integers, only the natural numbers.

Comment: @ancientmathematician If it doesn't work for integers then it doesn't work for natural numbers. So even if $x$ must be a natural number, then the series expansion should work for $x$ is a natural number. But it doesn't. Let $f(x)=\frac1{x+1}$ and $x=1$, then we get that $\frac12=\frac{\pi^2}6$ which isn't true obviously.

Comment: If $x$ is a natural number then the original formulas only hold where the $k$ are natural numbers and so your differentiations are unjustified.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Let $k=1$, then the formula remains largely the same.

Comment: Here's what I see. 

(1) The equation $\sum_{k=0}^xf(k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k) - f(k+x+1)$ requires that $x$ is a positive integer and a growth condition on $f(x)$ (the typo $k+x$ instead of $k+x+1$ is unimportant). Taking the derivative inside the infinite sum requires additional growth conditions. For positive integer values of $x$, the LHS is explicitly not continuous and so not differentiable at $x$ (unless $f(x)=0$). So you have one derivative that is usually not valid.

Comment: (2) $P_1(t)$ is discontinuous at integer values of $t$, so the integral defining $R_1$ is not differentiable and the fundamental theorem of calculus does not apply on the interval [0,x]. So you have a second derivative that is usually not valid.

(3) References and citations of Euler-Macluarin are often sloppy and full of typos. I prefer https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.